# Display Mysql data in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query, now how do i display the output in a `<p>` tag

```
SELECT COUNT( question_status) AS active_questions
FROM questions_table
WHERE question_status = "Active"
```

Comment: Generally you would, pick a database library (an ORM is usually a good idea), pick a template library, write a template, then pass the results of the call to the database lib to the template lib. The specifics depend on which libraries you use.

Comment: You would learn to use the mysqli or pdo library. Once you know that, it's very simple to make a database connection, run the query, fetch the result, and write it to the page. Look for a basic tutorial, and when you reach a point where you get stuck, you can post a specific question about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going back to complete basics:

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect($DB_hostname, $DB_username, $DB_password) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($DB_name, $connection);
        $query = mysql_query("
            SELECT COUNT(question_status) AS active_questions
            FROM questions_table
            WHERE question_status = "Active"
        ", $connection) or die(mysql_error());
        echo '<p>';
        while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            echo $myrow['active_questions'];
        }
        echo '</p>';
```

This is by no means exacting, it doesn't use any external (or valuable libraries, such as PDO), but should give you an idea of how to simplistically implement and render a result set.

You should explore/read-up on mysqli/PDO and others for further functionality/utility in time.

Comment: I was only looking for this bit  echo $myrow['active_questions']; thanks. i dont understand why people jump into conclusions so soon thanks

Comment: It's partly because many developers use far more advanced libraries to allow interoperability/security/flexibility and other factors. Start small but grow in experience! :)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

the links above both provide you with enough information to display the output. Don't forget to surround it with <p> tags.

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you included a bit of summary text about what will be helpful from those links and/or included some example code.